# Best Practice List/Array/ReadOnlyCollection creation (and usage)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, immutability

My code is littered with collections - not an unusual thing, I suppose.  However, usage of the various collection types isn't obvious nor trivial.  Generally, I'd like to use the type that's exposes the "best" API, and has the least syntactic noise.  (See [Best practice when returning an array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570083/best-practice-when-returning-an-array-of-values-net), [Using list arrays - Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337393/using-list-arrays-best-practices) for comparable questions).  There are guidelines suggesting what types to use **in an API**, but these are impractical in normal (non-API) code.

For instance:

```
new ReadOnlyCollection<Tuple<string,int>>(
    new List<Tuple<string,int>> {
        Tuple.Create("abc",3),
        Tuple.Create("def",37)
    }
)
```

`List`'s are a very common datastructure, but **creating them in this fashion involves quite a bit of syntactic noise** - and it can easily get even worse (e.g. dictionaries).  As it turns out, many lists are never changed, or at least never extended.  Of course `ReadOnlyCollection` introduces yet more syntactic noise, and it doesn't even convey quite what I mean; after all `ReadOnlyCollection` may wrap a *mutating* collection.  Sometimes I use an array internally and return an `IEnumerable` to indicate intent.  But most of these approaches have a very low signal-to-noise ratio; and that's absolutely critical to understanding code.

For the 99% of all code that is *not* a public API, it's not necessary to follow Framework Guidelines: however, I *still* want a comprehensible code and a type that communicates intent.

**So, what's the best-practice way to deal with the bog-standard task of making small collections to pass around values?**  Should array be preferred over `List` where possible?  Something else entirely?  What's the best way - clean, readable, reasonably efficient - of passing around such small collections?  In particular, **code should be obvious** to future maintainers that *have not* read this question and don't want to read swathes of API docs yet still understand what the intent is.  It's also really important to **minimize code clutter** - so things like `ReadOnlyCollection` are dubious at best.  Nothing wrong with wordy types for major API's with small surfaces, but not as a general practice inside a large codebase.

What's the best way to pass around lists of values without lots of code clutter (such as explicit type parameters) but that still communicates intent clearly?

**Edit:** clarified that this is about making short, clear code, not about public API's.

Comment: So, I've actually got [an open source library](https://bitbucket.org/dtao/tao.net) which includes an `IArray<T>` interface that I believe is ideal for precisely this purpose. See my updated answer for a bit more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

So, this isn't strictly speaking *new*; but this question convinced me to [go ahead and announce](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/the-elusive-iarrayt-interface-if-nobody-else-is-going-to-do-it-i-will/) [an open source project I've had in the works for a while](https://bitbucket.org/dtao/tao.net) (still a work in progress, but there's some useful stuff in there), which includes an `IArray<T>` interface (and implementations, naturally) that I think captures exactly what you want here: an indexed, read-only, even *covariant* (bonus!) **interface**.

Some benefits:

- It's not a concrete type like `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, so it doesn't tie you down to a specific implementation.
- It's not just a wrapper (like `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`), so it "really is" read-only.
- It clears the way for some really nice extension methods. So far the Tao.NET library only has two (I know, weak), but more are on the way. And you can easily make your own, too—just derive from `ArrayBase<T>` (also in the library) and override the `this[int]` and `Count` properties and you're done.

If this sounds promising to you, feel free to [check it out](https://bitbucket.org/dtao/tao.net) and let me know what you think.

---

It's not 100% clear to me *where* you're worried about this "syntactic noise": in *your* code or in *calling* code?

If you're tolerant of some "noise" in your own encapsulated code then I would suggest wrapping a `T[]` array and exposing an `IList<T>` which happens to be a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`:

```
class ThingsCollection
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<Thing> _things;

    public ThingsCollection()
    {
        Thing[] things = CreateThings();
        _things = Array.AsReadOnly(things);
    }

    public IList<Thing> Things
    {
        get { return _things; }
    }

    protected virtual Thing[] CreateThings()
    {
        // Whatever you want, obviously.
        return new Thing[0];
    }
}
```

Yes there is *some* noise on your end, but it's not bad. And the interface you expose is quite clean.

Another option is to make your own interface, [something like `IArray<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110440/why-is-there-no-iarrayt-interface-in-net), which wraps a `T[]` and provides a get-only indexer. Then expose that. This is basically  as clean as exposing a `T[]` but without falsely conveying the idea that items can be set by index.

Comment: I'd like to avoid noise in both callee and caller.  Exposing a ReadOnlyCollection as anything other than itself isn't necessary: after all, exposing it as an IList just gets confusing (where'd I get *this* IList from - can I modify it?), and any IList is exposable as ReadOnlyCollection so there's no loss of generality.

Comment: Thanks for the great link to the `IArray` discussion!

Comment: @Eamon: The reason I suggested `IList<T>` over `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is that I thought you were concerned about the wordiness of the name itself. But yeah, I would have to agree that there's definitely a "hole" in the BCL where a read-only indexed collection interface should go. `IList<T>` is just *too* multi-purpose.

Comment: Casting as a Ilist<T> allows modification of the underlying collection.  ReadOnlyCollection<T> is a much better work-around (since they didn't have IList<T> implement some sort of IReadOnlyList<T>).

Answer (score 4):

After hopefully understanding your question, i think you have to distinguish between what you create and manage within your class and what you make available to the outside world.

Within your class you can use whatever best fits your current task (pro/cons of `List` vs. `Array` vs. `Dictionary` vs. `LinkedList` vs. etc.). But this has maybe nothing to do about what you provide in your public properties or functions.

Within your public contract (properties and functions) you should give back the least type (or even better interface) that is needed. So just an `IList`, `ICollection`, `IDictionary`, `IEnumerable` of some public type. Thous leads that your consumer classes are just awaiting interfaces instead of concrete classes and so you can change the concrete implementation at a later stage without breaking your public contract (due to performance reasons use an `List<>` instead of a `LinkedList<>` or vice versa).

Comment: +1: This is the reason why : [Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) of the [SOLID Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29)

Comment: Perhaps I need to clarify my question: I'm specifically concerned with avoiding code-bloat and communicating intent.  Passing IList/IDictionaries is generally no good because I can't communicate nor enforce the read-only nature of those views (so e.g. IList is actively worse than an array here)

Comment: And as a second point, I want producers and consumers to be readable - so I'd like to keep calls to a minumum and avoid all explicit template arguments whereever possible.

Comment: @Eamon: Though I can see what you mean, technically `IList<T>` is capable of expressing intent since it has an `IsReadOnly` property. I will grant you that *nobody* ever looks at that, though. However, there is precedent for it in the BCL (for whatever that's worth); consider the `SortedList<TKey, TValue>.Keys` property, for example. Read-only, exposed as `IList<TKey>`.

Comment: Yeah, and when modifying code (and thus reasoning statically), `IsReadOnly` isn't much help anyhow - you want to *know* not *test* whether the list can be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not pass around `Lists`s if I can possibly help it.  Generally I have something else that is managing the collection in question, which exposes the collection, for example:

```
public class SomeCollection
{
    private List<SomeObject> m_Objects = new List<SomeObject>();

    // ctor
    public SomeCollection()
    {
        // Initialise list here, or wot-not/
    } // eo ctor


    public List<SomeObject> Objects { get { return m_Objects; } }
} // eo class SomeCollection
```

And so this would be the object passed around:

```
public void SomeFunction(SomeCollection _collection)
{
    // work with _collection.Objects
} // eo SomeFunction
```

I like this approach, because:

1) I can populate my values in the ctor.  They're there the momeny anyone `new`s `SomeCollection`.

2) I can restrict access, if I want, to the underlying list.  In my example I exposed it all, but you don't have to do this.  You can make it read-only if you want, or validate additions to the list, prior to adding them.

3) It's clean.  Far easier to read `SomeCollection` than `List<SomeObject>` everywhere.

4) If you suddenly realise that your collection of choice is inefficient, you can change the underlying collection type without having to go and change all the places where it got passed as a parameter (can you imagine the trouble you might have with, say, `List<String>`?)

Comment: I guess this is a kinda neat separation; but it makes consumers wordier (need to go .Objects everywhere), and it makes the construction wordier (can't use `.ToList` or collection initializers).  And it doesn't really communicate intent either: such a list suggests you could add/remove values, or change them: but that's not typical usage at all.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. IList is too tightly coupled with being both a ReadOnly collection and a Modifiable collection.  IList should have inherited from an IReadOnlyList.

Casting back to IReadOnlyList wouldn't require a explicit cast.  Casting forward would.

### 1.

Define your own class which implements IEnumerator, takes an IList in the new constructor, has a read only default item property taking an index, and does not include any properties/methods that could otherwise allow your list to me manipulated.

If you later want to allow modifying the ReadOnly wrapper like IReadOnlyCollection does, you can make another class which is a wrapper around your custom ReadOnly Collection and has the Insert/Add/Remove/RemoveAt/Clear/...implemented and cache those changes.

### 2.

Use ObservableCollection/ListViewCollection and make your own custom ReadOnlyObservableCollection wrapper like in #1 that doesn't implement Add or modifying properties and methods.

ObservableCollection can bind to ListViewCollection in such a way that changes to ListViewCollection do not get pushed back into ObservableCollection.  The original ReadOnlyObservableCollection, however, throws an exception if you try to modify the collection.

If you need backwards/forwards compatibility, make two new classes inheriting from these. Then Implement IBindingList and handle/translate CollectionChanged Event (INotifyCollectionChanged event) to the appropriate IBindingList events.

Then you can bind it to older DataGridView and WinForm controls, as well as WPF/Silverlight controls.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has created a [Guidelines for Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections) document which is a very informative list of DOs and DON'Ts that address most of your question.

It's a long list so here are the most relevant ones:

> DO prefer collections over arrays.
>
> DO NOT use ArrayList or List in public APIs. *(public properties, public parameters and return types of public methods)*
>
> DO NOT use Hashtable or Dictionary in public APIs.
>
> DO NOT use weakly typed collections in public APIs.
>
> DO use the least-specialized type possible as a parameter type. Most members taking collections as parameters use the IEnumerable interface.
>
> AVOID using ICollection or ICollection as a parameter just to access the Count property.
>
> DO use ReadOnlyCollection, a subclass of ReadOnlyCollection, or in rare cases IEnumerable for properties or return values representing read-only collections.

As the last point states, you shouldn't avoid ReadOnlyCollection like you were suggesting. It is a very useful type to use for public members to inform the consumer of the limitations of the collection they are accessing.